# PHP script not receiving data

Tags: php, postman, rest

I have been looking at several php codes trying to find out the problem with my code, and why it wont receive data from post
below is my php code can any one tell me whats up with it

i am trying to send audio data with the name of the audio file through this php file
the php script is supposed to receive the audio file create then audio object and then extract the name and audio part from the file but when i send the data to test it through postman i get 400 error message as i have set it up to indicate error but i do not understand why this is happening

```
<?php

include_once '../../configration/database.php';
include_once '../../objects/sound.php';
// JWT TOKEN VALIDATION


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$database = new Database();
$conn     = $database->getConnection();

// CONTROL

 $sound = new Sound($conn);

// make sure data is not empty
    if (
        !is_null($data->$filename)
        && !is_null($data->$extension)
        && !is_null($data->$waveform)   )
    {
    
    $sound->filename                  = $data->filename;
    $sound->extension               = $data->extension;
    $sound->waveform           = $data->waveform; 
    
    // create the product
    if ($sound->create_new())
    {
        
        http_response_code(200);
    }
    else
    {
        
        http_response_code(503);
        
        echo json_encode(array(
            "message" => "Unable to create sound."
        ));
    }
}

else {
    
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(array(
        "message" => "Unable to create sound. Data is incomplete."
    ));
}



?>
```

**the database.php file is as follows**

```
<?php
include_once 'GlobalConfig.php';

class Database
{

    public $conn;

    public function getConnection(){
        $config= new GlobalConfig();
        $this->conn = null;

        try{
            $dsn = "mysql:host={$config->host};port={$config->port};dbname={$config->db_name};charset=utf8";

            $this->conn = new PDO($dsn, $config->username, $config->password);
            $this->conn->exec("set names utf8");
        }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }

    public function getConnectionAndValidate($data){

        $this->conn = null;
        $config= new GlobalConfig();

        try{
            $dsn = "mysql:host={$config->host};port={$config->port};dbname={$config->db_name};charset=utf8";

            $this->conn = new PDO($dsn, $config->username, $config->password);
            $this->conn->exec("set names utf8");
            }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        if (!validateToken($data->JWT, $data->UserID, $this->conn)){
          http_response_code(401);
        echo "Authorization: declined";
          exit();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }

}
```

**THE sound.php FILE IS AS FOLLOWS**

```
<?php
class Sound
{
    
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "";
    public $filename;
    public $extension;
    public $waveform;
    public $path;
 
 
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->conn = $db;
    }   

    function create_new()
    {
        
        $this->path = $this->filename .".". $this->extension;
       
            $myfile = fopen($this->path, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
             
            fwrite($myfile, $this->waveform);
             
            
            fclose($myfile);
        

        // $query = " INSERT INTO `tbl_address` 
        // (`contact_number`,`UserID` ,`billing_street_address`, `billing_city_address`, `billing_state_address`, `billing_country_address`, `billing_zip`,
        //  `shipping_street_address`, `shipping_city_address`, `shipping_state_address`, `shipping_country_address`, `shipping_zip`) 

        // VALUES (:contact_number,'$this->user_id', :billing_street_address, :billing_city_address, :billing_state_address, :billing_country_address, :billing_zip, 
        // :shipping_street_address, :shipping_city_address, :shipping_state_address, :shipping_country_address, :shipping_zip);";
        
        // $stmt                           = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        // $this->contact_number           = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->contact_number));
        // $this->billing_street_address   = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->billing_street_address));
        // $this->billing_city_address     = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->billing_city_address));
        // $this->billing_state_address    = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->billing_state_address));
        // $this->billing_country_address  = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->billing_country_address));
        // $this->billing_zip              = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->billing_zip));
        // $this->shipping_street_address  = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->shipping_street_address));
        // $this->shipping_city_address    = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->shipping_city_address));
        // $this->shipping_state_address   = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->shipping_state_address));
        // $this->shipping_country_address = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->shipping_country_address));
        // $this->shipping_zip             = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->shipping_zip));
        
        // // bind values
        // $stmt->bindParam(":contact_number", $this->contact_number);
        // $stmt->bindParam(":billing_street_address", $this->billing_street_address);
        // $stmt->bindParam(":billing_city_address", $this->billing_city_address);
        // $stmt->bindParam(":billing_state_address", $this->billing_state_address);
        // $stmt->bindParam(":billing_country_address", $this->billing_country_address);
        // $stmt->bindParam(":billing_zip", $this->billing_zip);
        // $stmt->bindParam(":shipping_street_address", $this->shipping_street_address);
        // $stmt->bindParam(":shipping_city_address", $this->shipping_city_address);
        // $stmt->bindParam(":shipping_state_address", $this->shipping_state_address);
        // $stmt->bindParam(":shipping_country_address", $this->shipping_country_address);
        // $stmt->bindParam(":shipping_zip", $this->shipping_zip);
        
        // if ($stmt->execute()) {
        //         $this->address_id = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
        // } 
        // else {
        //     echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to get address."));                        
        // }



    }

   
    
}
?>
```

Comment: This is a great time for you to start learning how to debug. A Google search for something like "how to debug PHP" will get you started. If you're using an IDE, it probably has helpful debugging tools. Even if you're not, you can still do some basic debugging by outputting key values throughout your code, running it, and observing that output. Use this process to narrow down the problem. If your code is doing something you don't expect, then somewhere in your code a specific operation is producing a result you didn't expect. Find that operation, determine the values at the time.

Comment: The error i receive is as follows
Connection error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Comment: Related to @JohnConde's comment, I'd also suggest avoiding `try/catch` during the early phase of development, turn on [PDO loud exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) and turning on full PHP error reporting.